# Can native code cause memory corruption in Java code in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, dalvik, memory-corruption

In Android, when we call native code via JNI, can it corrupt the Dalvik VM, and the Java code running inside it?

For example, suppose we have this C method and we call it via JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MemoryCorruptor_corruptMemory()
{
    while (1) {
        char *p = randomAddress();
        *p = randomChar();
    }
}
```

If the VM just loads the .so files and the native code is running in the **same context/address space** as the VM, then I assume the VM could get corrupted.

On the other hand, if the VM creates a child process to hold the .so files and uses some form of IPC to call methods, then the Java code can't get corrupted by the native code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native code runs in the same process as the Java code it interacts with via JNI, so yes, it is very much able to corrupt key data structures.  Most often you might see this as a crash within the library implementing the VM itself, shortly after the return from misbehaving native code, but in theory another thread could mis-operate.

To the extent that there is isolation between native and VM-hosted code of the same process, it is merely that the information needed to *usefully* and *safely* modify implementation data structures is only available to a limited degree under certain JNI support calls - but it is all exposed to blindfolded poking, if your native code does that.  Of course it is also possible that your code will crash the process by attempting an illegal access itself.  Depending on the details of the VM implementation some of the "code" of the app may well be in read-only memory pages, and attempting to write to those would cause a memory protection fault.  However, data, and any JIT "compiled on the fly" code will presumably be in a writable pages.  And actively nefarious code can change the protection settings, swapping read-only file-backed mappings for writable anonymous pages with the same contents if necessary.

It is possible to run components of an Android app in a distinct process, but that will have its own VM wrapping any JNI code you use there - classes like Activity and Service are fundamentally Java level, even if you use stock JNI glue Java code to do the work in a native version.  Some web browser apps for example may do this, to put a little more isolation around their javascript interpreter engines.

It has also been possible (to date) to start up an independent native-only process and talk to it via IPC, however this is not encouraged as it will lack the lifecycle hooks for management by Android, and there are some tricky parts of it you will have to accomplish yourself.  Further, such a program cannot use most Java-defined Android platform APIs, or at least not in a portable manner.  Historically people have resorted to this primarily when using an "su" root shim on a hacked device to start up a helper process running as the superuser, or occasionally as a pathway to port a complicated Linux-style tool without re-architecting it as a JNI library.

Comment: FWIW, the DEX bytecode is mapped read-only, though the mappings can be altered (notably for setting/clearing debug breakpoints). The Dalvik VM includes a feature for storing internal VM data structures on read-only pages (dig for "LinearAlloc" if you're curious), which can sometimes be helpful for finding corruption, but enabling it requires recompiling the VM. The most common form of corruption is trashing of the managed heap. The switch from pointers to indices for JNI global/local refs in ICS had the useful side-effect of stopping some of that by keeping pointers off the stack.